# How can I get one property from a collection and assign it to an array?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I thought this would be easy, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I have a model in my Entity Framework project called _context.Galaxy.

It contains a bunch of different properties, but I only want to retrieve the name and create a string array of all the galaxy names in the database.

Here is my code:

```
var allGalaxyNames = _context.Galaxy
    .Select(x => new
    {
        GalaxyName = x.Name.ToString()
    }).ToArray();


    string[] AllGalaxys = allGalaxyNames
```

I keep getting this error no matter what I try:

```
 Cannot implicitly convert type '<anonymous type: string GalaxyName>[]' to 'string[]'
```

How can I get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: In the `Select` method You project the results to an anonymous type with `GalaxyName` property and make it an array, so `allGalaxyNames` is an array of anonymous class objects. Then You try to assign it to `string[] AllGalaxys`, which causes the issue.
To make it work just write `_context.Galaxy.Select(x => x.Name.ToString());` instead, when selecting data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the anonymous object, just return a string from the `Select`.

```
string[] allGalaxyNames = _context.Galaxy
    .Select(x => x.Name.ToString())
    .ToArray();
```